# MS Edge crashing when rendering SVG textPath

Tags: svg, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I am trying to implement a complex chart in SVG, and there is a specific combination of attributes that sends the browser into a loop, refreshing the page a couple of times, then landing on an error page that says:

> **This page is having a problem loading**
>
> We tried to load this page for you a few times, but there is still a problem with this site. We know you have better things to do than to watch this page reload over and over again so try coming back to this page later.

This happens when I have a `textPath` attached to a `path`, with `text-anchor` set to `middle` or `end` (`start` works fine).

Here is some sample code, and [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/miwavinawe/1)

```
<svg>
  <path d="M10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10" id="pathId"></path>
  <text text-anchor="middle">
    <textPath xlink:href="#pathId">Some long text on the path</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Testing on:

Windows 10, version 1607, OS Build 14393

Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0 / Microsoft EdgeHTML 14.14393

---

Why is this happening? how can I fix this?

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is an issue on Microsoft's side - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8502609/

The issue went away after I updated Microsoft Edge to version 38.14393.1066.0